# What are post clicks on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

*Similar to my [previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54503/57036)*. I started a short paid ad campaign for [my page](https://www.facebook.com/2222FacesCom). Once I opened a New Page Insights, I saw the *Engagement* box, which says:

[image]

What are “Post Clicks”? All posts on my page are not clickable. I thought that a Facebook user can't click on a post itself. He or she can only click on *Share*, *Like* or *Comment*.

How can I have 14 post clicks, if my page has **zero likes, zero comments and zero shares**? From where did that 49 came from? What am I missing?

BTW: I asked the same question on [Facebook Community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1392312167692406).

Answer (score 1):

Post clicks are "the total number of clicks on your post, not including likes, comments, or shares. "

See more: [Social Media Examiner: Facebook insights](http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/new-facebook-insights/)

Comment: That would mean, that if I post a photo and someone clicks on it, to see the larger version, that counts like one _post click_, right?